# Сортировка списка в списке, по наибольшему значению последнего элемента вложенного списка

Tags: python-3.x, сортировка, список

```
# Имеется список "а" в который вложены еще несколько списков, необходимо отсортировать исходный список
# по наибольшему значению последнего элемента воженного списка (список "b").

# был список "а"
# a[x][-1] = 8, 5, 6, 2
a = [[1, 2, 8], [1, 2, 34, 5, 2, 45, 5], [2, 2, 27, 8, 2, 6],  [56, 23, 5345, 1, 2]]

# стал список "b"
# b[x][-1] = 2, 5, 6, 8
b = [[56, 23, 5345, 1, 2], [1, 2, 34, 5, 2, 45, 5], [2, 2, 27, 8, 2, 6], [1, 2, 8]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я может чего-то не понимаю, но такой вариант подойдет?

```
a = [[1, 2, 8], [1, 2, 34, 5, 2, 45, 5], [2, 2, 27, 8, 2, 6],  [56, 23, 5345, 1, 2]]

b = sorted(a, key=lambda arr: arr[-1])
```

ну или если сортировать тот же список, то

```
a.sort(key=lambda arr: arr[-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [[1, 2, 8], [1, 2, 34, 5, 2, 45, 5], [2, 2, 27, 8, 2, 6],  [56, 23, 5345, 1, 2]]

d1 = {index: i[-1] for index, i in enumerate(a)}

b = []
for i in sorted(d1.values()):
    for key, value in d1.items():
        if value == i:
            b.append(a[key])
print(b)
```

Можно свернуть:

```
a = [[1, 2, 8], [1, 2, 34, 5, 2, 45, 5], [2, 2, 27, 8, 2, 6],  [56, 23, 5345, 1, 2]]
d1 = {index: i[-1] for index, i in enumerate(a)}
b = [a[key] for i in sorted(d1.values()) for key, value in d1.items() if value == i]
print(b)
```

Вывод:

```
[[56, 23, 5345, 1, 2], [1, 2, 34, 5, 2, 45, 5], [2, 2, 27, 8, 2, 6], [1, 2, 8]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def custom_key(lst): #  метод, изменяющий ключ, по которому будет проводиться сортировка
    return lst[-1] #  возвращаем последний элемент вложенного списка

b = a.copy() #  создаем копию списка а
b.sort(key=custom_key) #  сортируем по последнему элементу вложенного списка
print(b) #  выводим результат
```